# Send XML content to a JMS queue using Java

Tags: java, jms

Can anyone help me to send XML file (XML message) through JMS producer, I am trying to do it as `ByteMessage`, but still cannot do it.

I have a **JMS** produced which need to read XML file and send as a message. I was trying to do it from **ByteMessage** and did not succeed, I'm looking for a better method to do this correctly, Please see below code snippet.

```
ByteMessage textMessage = session.createByteMessage(message);
```

Comment: Please include the code you've written so far. The more details you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a `TextMessage` and set the body of the message with `setText(<your xml>)` with your xml
Really straight forward...
`ByteMessage` is for ... binary data (eg zip files)